# Difference between Perl backticks and pipe

Tags: perl

I have an executable tool which return data separated by tabs as output , the data is very huge ,and want the output of the tool be an input for Perl program for further processing , what is the preferred way from performance perspective to use

```
@res=`mytool`
```

and processing @res

or use the pipe operator to read the tool while returning the results an process it something like the below :

```
open(RES, "mytool |") or die "Couldn't fork: $!\n";
while (<RES>) { # ... }
```

Comment: Performance comes down to benchmarks. You'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: The big difference, of course, is that the former loads the entire output into an array, while the latter reads only one line at a time.

Comment: Perl TMTOWTDI: `qx()`...

Comment: @Gilles Quenot, `\`...\``, `qx\`...\`` and `readpipe(qq\`...\`)` are all the same op. So not another way.

Comment: @Gilles Quenot, Fine, removed mention of system :) My comment still stands, though

Comment: OK, just another way to call the same thing, agree. I think `qx()` is like shell `$( )` more readable than backticks

Comment: @ikegami regarding your second comment, there's will be a real difference with the size of the treated data, in term of performances.

Comment: huh? You should be providing the same data to both approaches when benchmarking, and it should be representative of your actual data. I don't know why you're talking about different data sizes.

Comment: Side note: Prefer lexical file handles and the three-argument form of `open`: `open my $RES, "-|", "mytool" or die "...";`

Answer (score 2):

The second form will almost always be quicker than the first (at least if your code and the code providing the list will take some time to compute).

Here an easy example:

```
use strict;

use Benchmark qw(:all) ;
timethis (3,\&backtick );
timethis (3,\&pipe);

sub backtick {
    my @res=`locate .ssh`;
    my $count =0;
    foreach my $line (@res) {
           select(undef,undef,undef, .02); #20-millisecond delay
           $count += length($line);
    }
    print "$count \n";
}

sub  pipe{
    local *RES;
    open(RES, "locate .ssh |") or die "Couldn't fork: $!\n";

    my $count =0;
    while (<RES>) { # 
           select(undef,undef,undef, .02); #20-millisecond delay
           $count += length($_);
    }
    print "$count \n";
}
```

will on my pc print:

```
4921
4921
4921
timethis 3: 21 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr  0.00 sys + 15.11 cusr  0.19 csys = 15.                                                                  30 CPU) @  0.20/s (n=3)
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
4921
4921
4921
timethis 3: 16 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr  0.00 sys + 15.15 cusr  0.18 csys = 15.                                                                  33 CPU) @  0.20/s (n=3)
```

(The locate .ssh takes about 5 seconds to finish)